# How can I append a variable text to last line of file via command line?

Tags: bash, sed

could you please tell me how I (a Linux-User) can add text to the last line of a text-file?

I have this so far:

```
APPEND='Some/Path which is/variable'
sed '${s/$/$APPEND/}' test.txt
```

It works, but $APPEND is added insted of the content of the variable. I know the reason for this is the singe quote (') I used for sed. 
But when I simply replace ' by ", no text gets added to the file.

Do you know a solution for this? I don't insist on using `sed`, it's only the first command line tool that came in my mind. You may use every standard command line program you like.

edit: I've just tried this:

```
$ sed '${s/$/'"$APPEND/}" test.txt
sed: -e Ausdruck #1, Zeichen 11: Unbekannte Option für `s'
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
echo "$(cat $FILE)$APPEND" > $FILE
```

This was what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to append data is with file redirection.

```
echo $APPEND >>test.txt
```

Comment: This will add the text in the next line. I would like to append the text in the same line.

Answer (score 7):

Using this as input:

```
1 a line
2 another line
3 one more
```

and this bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash

APPEND='42 is the answer'

sed "s|$|${APPEND}|" input
```

outputs:

```
1 a line42 is the answer
2 another line42 is the answer
3 one more42 is the answer
```

Solution using awk:

```
BEGIN {s="42 is the answer"}

{lines[NR]=$0 }

END {
    for (i = 1; i < NR; i++)
        print lines[i]
    print lines[NR], s
}
```

Comment: This is different from the question that ask for only appending to the last line. Though, this will append to the end of each line. 

But, I must say "This is what I need". Thank you Fredrik!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '${s/$/'"$APPEND"'/}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a semicolon after the sed substitution command!

```
(
set -xv
APPEND=" word"
echo '
1
2
3' |
sed '${s/$/'"${APPEND}"'/;}'
#sed "\${s/$/${APPEND}/;}"
)
```