# Append content from variable to log file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a script and trying to append the content from my variables to a .log file. I saw on another post([How can I append a variable text to last line of file via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625148/how-can-i-append-a-variable-text-to-last-line-of-file-via-command-line)) that you can do this using echo "$(cat $FILE)$APPEND" > $FILE. I tried doing that and it’s able to run my script without errors and give the answers I need through terminal but it doesn’t append it to my log file. Can anyone please give me any pointers?

```
#!/bin/bash
mdate=echo date
mcpu=echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2 |tail -1|awk ‘{print $15}’)]%
mmem=free | grep Mem | awk ‘{print $3/$2 * 100.0}’
sudo cat /dev/null > /home/daniel/systemstatus.log
echo “$(cat $systemstatus.log)$mdate” >> $systemstatus.log
echo “$(cat $systemstatus.log)$mcpu” >> $systemstatus.log
echo “$(cat $systemstatus.log)$mmem” >> $systemstatus.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
mdate=$(echo date)
mcpu=$(echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2 |tail -1|awk '{print $15}')]%)
mmem=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}')
>/home/daniel/systemstatus.log
echo “$(cat $systemstatus.log)$mdate” >> systemstatus.log
echo “$(cat $systemstatus.log)$mcpu” >> systemstatus.log
echo “$(cat $systemstatus.log)$mmem” >> systemstatus.log
```

Note that if you would like to store the the output of a command in bash you should round the command in **$()** or `` However, the usage of grave accents is now deprecated.

Furthermore, using **cat /dev/null >** to empty a file in Linux would basically have the same result as simply using **>**

As for the issue that you are experiencing, note that appending **$** before any word basically makes the script/command to look for a variable with such name instead of the file name.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Your code requires several modifications, you cannot assign variables with the output of commands the way you tried to, you need to use command substitutions (`var=$(command)`) :

```
mdate=$(date)
mcpu=$(( 100 - $(vmstat 1 2 | tail -1| awk '{print $15}') ))
mmem=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}')
```

Your post contains quotes that are not valid for the shell.  Use single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` (each has its purpose).

But the logging part is simpler than you thought

```
logfile=/home/daniel/systemstatus.log
echo "$mdate" >"$logfile"  # Overwrites the previous log file
echo "$mcpu"  >>"$logfile" # Appends to the log file
echo "$mmem"  >>"$logfile" # Appends to the log file
```

If the only reason for capturing the output of your commands in variables is for logging you can simplify further by redirecting to your log file without capturing the output.

```
date >"$logfile" # Overwrites the previous log file
echo $(( 100 - $(vmstat 1 2 | tail -1| awk '{print $15}') )) >>"$logfile"
free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}' >>"$logfile"
```

You can even put the redirection first, which may be cleaner to the eye depending on your taste :

```
>"$logfile"  date # Overwrites the previous log file
>>"$logfile" echo $(( 100 - $(vmstat 1 2 | tail -1| awk '{print $15}') ))
>>"$logfile" free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
```

This answer assumes your commands actually work (I have not tested them).

Comment: thanks so much for the help buddy, this did it and the explanations were great too!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `$` before `systemstatus`

When you type `$systemstatus`, it means a variable named "systemstatus", not the systemstatus file.

Comment: I suppose the OP created a file `.log` in the current directory